# Could not add dependency for PowerMock 1.1.1

Tags: maven, powermock

I'm using a PowerMock version 1.1.1 and its dependencies. When I added dependencies to pom.xml, I got error missing artifact.

I defined like that:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That looks like a rather old version.  Is it possible to use a newer version?

Comment: try a newer version or search it http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ca%3A%22powermock-core%22